Is the "out" folder of an IntelliJ project supposed to pop up only after I run the program for the first time?
I'm new to Java, and had just started working with IntelliJ IDEA.
I opened a new project, ran the sample code, and only then did the "out" folder appear.
Here is what happened and how it looks.
Is this normal?

Do you have any reason to believe it's anything other than normal? (Did or did this cause you a concrete problem?)

The out folder in your project contains the compiled classes. It will be created the first time you build the project. Running a class implicitly causes IntelliJ to build it, which is what you're seeing.
In short - yes, it's normal, don't sweat it.
